# MATLAB -- Disable background image data cursor

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am currently working on a program involving shop routing, involving an image map obtained from google maps in the background.

When I try to use the data cursor (to show some irrelevant information), I need to click exactly the right pixel to get the data assigned to the plotted points, else I get a data tip error. Is there any way to disable data cursor mode for the background image while enabling it for the scattered points? 
My figure looks like this:

[image: Figure]

edit: In case this helps, the background is defined as an image with following properties:
**CData**: [1280×1280×3 double]
**CDataMapping**: 'direct'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the `HitTest` property of your background image to `off` - that way the datatip will only show when you click on your data of interest.